# In elasticsearch, how to make an indexed field to have lucene IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use elasticsearch to enhance my image search project which was implemented with Lucene. I'm having a hard time finding a way to config elasticsearch to make an indexed field have Lucene `IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS`.

The working Lucene indexing code is:

```
Document doc = new Document();

FieldType myFieldType = new FieldType();

myFieldType.setIndexed(true);
myFieldType.setOmitNorms(true);
myFieldType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);  // tell indexer to store image token's positions, offsets, and payloads

myFieldType.setStored(false);
myFieldType.setTokenized(true);
myFieldType.freeze();

doc.add(new Field("tokens", tokenStream_w_payload, myFieldType));

indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
```

I had no problems making my analyzer and my query handler as elasticsearch plugins, but using default elasticsearch settings, I cannot get any information about positions, offsets, and payloads from Lucene `TermsEnum` and `DocsAndPositionsEnum` objects initialized from the `AtomicReaderContext` of the index for tokens that I can see there.

Comment: I am following elasticsearch document and playing with field mapping setting "index_options" with various suggested values:

Comment: I am following elasticsearch menu https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html and playing with field mapping setting "index_options" with various suggested values.

It does not help. e.g., 

   curl -s -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/' -d '{

  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "tokens": {
          "type": "string",
          "index" : "analyzed",
          "store" : "yes",
          "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
          "index_options" : "offsets"

         }
      }
    }
  }
 }'

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

It appears that I have to implement and plugin my own Analyzer. The common Analyzers seams not to generate and support offsets and payloads.

Here is my working fields mapping:

```
    curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/sm101" -d'
    {
       "mappings": {
         "sample": {
           "properties": {

             "DOC_ID" : {"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes" },
             "NAME" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "yes" },

             "tokens": {
               "type": "string",
               "store" : "yes",
               "index" : "analyzed",
               "analyzer": "image_starmap",

               "index_options" : "offsets",           

               "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads"
             },

             "filepath" : {
               "type": "string",
               "store" : "yes",
               "index" : "analyzed"
             }
           }
         }
       }
    }'
```

It works nicely with my complex ImageStarmapSpansQuery of image search.